# How do I get translated error messages in sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am using Sequel. How do I get ActiveModel-style translated errors?

### Example

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  def validate
    super
    errors.add(:email, :invalid)
  end
end

@user = User.new
@user.save # => false
@user.errors.full_messages # => ["email invalid"]
```

I want it to return a translated error using the `config/locales` data. When `I18n.locale = :en` it should return `["Email is invalid"]`, when `I18n.locale = :de` it should return `["Derrrrr E-Reichspost ist ungültig"]` (and so on). **How can I get translated error messages in sequel?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the validation_helpers plugin DEFAULT_OPTIONS.  Here's an example: http://pastie.org/4251873